Projection matrices, $\|P-Q\| = \|(I-P)Q\|$?
Let $P\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be projection matrices, where $P = AA^T$ and $Q = BB^T$. Here $A, B \in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$ have orthonormal columns, meaning that $A^TA = B^TB = I_k$. Do we have that
$$
\|P-Q\| = \|(I-P)Q\|?
$$
Here I am thinking about the spectral norm.
Comments: We know they are off by at most two times since
$$
\|P-Q\| \le \|(I-P)Q\| + \|(I-Q)P\| = \|(Q-P)Q\| + \|(P-Q)P\| \le 2\|P-Q\|.
$$

What is the norm here? Spectral norm, Frobenius norm, or something else?

I am thinking about the spectral norm. Thanks!

You definitely need more restrictions; the choice $P = I$ and $Q\neq I$ reveals the conjectured equality as false: the LHS being $>0$ then, whereas the RHS is zero.

@Hanno That $A^TA = B^TB = I_k$ while $P = AA^T$ and $Q = BB^T$ already implies $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, namely $k$.

I wanted to say that $A$ and $B$ have orthonormal columns. Then if $P=I_d$, meaning that $d=k$, we will have $Q=BB^T=I$.

@Nicole Your conditions can simply be summarized by saying $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal projections of the same rank, which is what I used in my answer.

I agree with you. Thank you!

An essentially identical question was posted and closed a few months ago.

@user1551 That question was already deleted, which, at least from the point of view of duplication, means the current question is acceptable, I believe? (Though admittedly I did cheat a bit by basically copying my own answer from there.)

@DavidGao In view of duplication, yes, but the other one was closed and then deleted because it was thought to be lacking context, and the current question has not any more context, either. I disagree with its closure, but I also doubt the appropriateness of moving the answers from there to here.

@user1551 I’d say this one does have more context, given that the OP included a comment outlining some partial progress they made, so it’s not just problem statement. In any case though, unless a question has already garnered some close votes and is clearly going to be closed, I think it’s generally reasonable to answer it. Given that this question has three upvotes, no downvotes, and no close votes, the community also seems to think it’s appropriate to answer this question. At least, I don’t have any issue answering it, nor do I think it’s a problem if you move your answer here as well.

Let $P, Q$ be two orthogonal projections of the same rank on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (this is also true if we are instead on $\mathbb{C}^d$, with the same proof). We need to prove that $\|P - Q\| = \|P^\perp Q\|$.
Now, if $P = Q$, then $\|P - Q\| = 0 = \|P^\perp Q\|$. If $\text{range}(P^\perp) \cap \text{range}(Q) \neq \{0\}$. Then we may choose a unit vector $h \in \text{range}(P^\perp) \cap \text{range}(Q)$ and see that,
$$1 = \|h\| = \|P^\perp Qh\| \leq \|P^\perp Q\|\|h\| = \|P^\perp Q\| \leq \|P^\perp\|\|Q\| = 1$$
So $\|P^\perp Q\| = 1$. On the other hand, $-I \leq -Q \leq P - Q \leq P \leq I$, so $\|P - Q\| \leq 1$, and,
$$1 = \|-h\| = \|(P - Q)h\| \leq \|P - Q\|\|h\| = \|P - Q\|$$
Thus, $\|P - Q\| = 1 = \|P^\perp Q\|$.
Finally, we consider the case where $P \neq Q$ and $\text{range}(P^\perp) \cap \text{range}(Q) = \{0\}$. Since $P, Q$ have the same rank, $\dim(\text{range}(P^\perp)) + \dim(\text{range}(Q)) = d$, so $\mathbb{R}^d = \text{range}(P^\perp) \oplus \text{range}(Q)$. Note that the direct sum is only as linear spaces - the two summands may not be orthogonal. Regardless, any vector $h$ can be written uniquely as,
$$h = h_1 + h_2$$
where $h_1 \in \text{range}(P^\perp)$ and $h_2 \in \text{range}(Q)$.
Note that as $P - Q$ is symmetric (self-adjoint, if instead we are in the complex case), its spectral norm equals its spectral radius. As $P \neq Q$, there is at least one nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $h$, decomposed as above, be an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$, then,
$$\lambda h_1 + \lambda h_2 = \lambda h = (P - Q)h = - Qh_1 + Ph_2 - h_2 = - P^\perp h_2 - Qh_1$$
As $\mathbb{R}^d = \text{range}(P^\perp) \oplus \text{range}(Q)$, we have,
$$\lambda h_1 = -P^\perp h_2 \;\;\text{and}\;\; \lambda h_2 = -Qh_1$$
Note that this implies $h_1 \neq 0$, as otherwise $h_2 = -\frac{1}{\lambda}Qh_1 = 0$ and $h = h_1 + h_2 = 0$, a contradiction. Thus, $h_1 \in \text{range}(P^\perp)$ is such that $P^\perp Qh_1 = -\lambda P^\perp h_2 = \lambda^2 h_1$, so $h_1$ is an eigenvector in $\text{range}(P^\perp)$ of $P^\perp Q$, with eigenvalue $\lambda^2$. Conversely, note that on $\text{range}(P^\perp)$, we have $P^\perp Q = P^\perp QP^\perp$ is symmetric, positive semi-definite, so all its nonzero eigenvalues are strictly positive. (Note that per above, it does have nonzero eigenvalues.) Thus, any nonzero eigenvalue may be written as $\lambda^2$ for some $\lambda \neq 0$. If $h_1 \in \text{range}(P^\perp)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda^2$, then $h = h_1 - \frac{1}{\lambda}Qh_1$ is an eigenvector of $P - Q$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Indeed, as $\mathbb{R}^d = \text{range}(P^\perp) \oplus \text{range}(Q)$ and $h_1 \neq 0$, we have $h \neq 0$. And,
$$\begin{split}
(P - Q)h &= -Qh_1 - \frac{1}{\lambda}PQh_1 + \frac{1}{\lambda}Qh_1\\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda}P^\perp Qh_1 - Qh_1\\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda}\lambda^2h_1 - Qh_1\\
&= \lambda(h_1 - \frac{1}{\lambda}Qh_1)\\
&= \lambda h
\end{split}$$
Thus, for any nonzero $\lambda \neq 0$, it is an eigenvalue of $P - Q$ iff $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $P^\perp QP^\perp$ and $P^\perp QP^\perp$ only has nonnegative eigenvalues. So, as both are symmetric and as such their spectral norms coincide with their spectral radii,
$$\|P - Q\| = \sqrt{\|P^\perp QP^\perp\|} = \sqrt{\|P^\perp QQP^\perp\|} = \|P^\perp Q\|$$
